# Best way to reuse common functions between ASPX pages ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, code-reuse

I have a bunch of functions that are used across multiple ASPX files. I want to condense these down to one file to be used for all the ASPX files. I have a few ideas but I want to know what the accepted method to doing this would be. I have an idea to just create a class to put them in.

However, I was wondering if i could put them in a ascx page, but that does not look like the solution I'm looking for.

Is there a accepted method for this type of situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it can be done by creating a library in the project, and referencing the namespace in your aspx files.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="sharedfunctionlibrarynamespace" %>
```

I also found a similar post - [Reusing same functions in different .aspx files/making function library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6091440/1437962)

As you have also mentioned, another approach is to create a base class from which all of your page classes will derive. That will work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you see any benefit to creating a library over just using a base class?

Comment: I would look at the trade-offs. Base-class approach might be useful if you use this functions only in one module(sub-domain). However, having them as a separate library, would allow reuse in other sub-domains as well, where your classes do not inherit from base class.